# Удаление подстроки начиная с позиции и с количеством элементов

Tags: c#, консоль, строки

Всем привет.
Как в C# сделать удаление подстроки
Например есть строка

```
string str = "hello world!"
delete(str,6,5); //Удаление элементов начиная с 6 до 11, .т.к. 5 элементов удаляется
```

Результат

```
  str = "hello !";
```

В C# есть remove, но он не так работает. Есть вариант split, тоже как то не то.

Второй пример

заданы числа

```
str = "12345678";
delete(s2,3,4);
Result:
str = "1238"
```

Comment: Строки в C# неизменяемые, так что модифицировать саму строку вы не сможете без грязных трюков. Так что смотрите ответ @DreamChild.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

я, может, что-то не понимаю..но чем не устраивает  Remove? Вот такой, скажем:

```
    string str = "hello world!";
    str = str.Remove(6, 5); // результат = "hello !"
```

Comment: facepalm)
думал remove с одним параметром.

Comment: пожалуйста. Будьте внимательнее все же

Answer (score 3):

Если надо без Remove(), то можно подстроками:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var startRemove = 6;
var lengthRemove = 5;
var newStr = str.Substring(0, startRemove - 1) + str.Substring(startRemove + lengthRemove);
```

результат см тут http://ideone.com/EOEuku

Comment: тоже правильный ответ +1

Comment: спасибо за идею!

Comment: во-первых, результат неверный ("hello !" != "hello!"). А во-вторых, к чему эти извращения аж на 5 строк?

Comment: Во первых, результат верный ибо элементы массивов (а строка по сути массив символов) принято считать с нуля. Во вторых эти "извращения" можно отрефакторить в одну строку, просто я вынес константы в переменные, чтобы было понятнее. В третьих, считаю, что вариант с Remove() лучше, ибо не надо изобретать велосипеды.